# How do you prefer functions to fail in python

Tags: python, styles

I'm currently writing a style guide for programmers and just wondered how you prefer functions to fail soft.

I'm not talking about actual errors but for instance if you have a function that is should return a parameter from the command line and that parameter is not found.

Should the function:

- Return an empty string
- Return False
- Return a constant "fail" string
- Raise an exception that the caller can catch in a try

I'm seeing a combination of all of these and wondered, as a programmer which you prefer to see when using a library.

(My preference is 2 so you can do

```
thing=getsomething(thing_to_get)
if thing:
  #deal with thing
else:
  #deal with missing thing
```

)

Comment: A function might fail for so many reasons, you just mention a 'resource not found' scenario. In my opinion it depends from situation to situation (e.g. division by zero, connection to server lost, index out of bound...) so it is hard to say I prefer 1,2,3,4 ... I might prefer each of them independently depending on the case

Comment: what is the something is a booleaan? That is the problem with returning fixed things, the consumer has to know what will be returned, and if he knows he can use try, except which is so cheap in python that is always worth doing. Longstory short use try and except and let the consumer decide

Comment: @jacosalari - Tha's kind of what I'm coming to. Horses for courses.

Comment: @e.sierra - Interesting scenario. I need to think about that one :) One of my problems with the Exception method is getting coders to actually use trys.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your program but most of the time it's better to send a message to the user and tell him why the program can't be executed. for example if the user should provide some input argument but he didn't, you can print a message and help the user how to run program correctly.

You should consider that it's not acceptable for an ideal program to terminate suddenly with an error! even with a clear message. instead it's better to give the user why program can't run and give him another chance to try.

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of try...except? A custom Exception can give the appropriate guidance ie (raise Exception("The parameter {0} could not be found in {1)".format(parametername,filename)

Then the consumer code can decide whether to default the parameter, elegantly terminate the code with a message to the end user or do some other remedial action (eg ask the user for a value.

Comment: Try except is originally for developer not the final user. Suppose that you're working with Photoshop and suddenly it terminates with an error!! It's awkward. As I told you, the program should provide a message and terminate current request and give another chance to user.

Comment: I agree that the user should not see the error and it should be caught in the code.

But what we are talking about here are functions that are called by a developer. I can't see any circumstances where a user would call directly into a function.